# How do I detect duplicate values within an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I have an array that looks like:

```
a = [cat, dog, cat, mouse, rat, dog, cat]
```

How do I cycle through that, and do something with duplicates - e.g. say delete them?

In other words, if I did `a.each do |i|`, how do I evaluate a[0], against a[1], a[2], a[3]...and then when I find the one I want, say a[2] in this case has the first duplicate, I then push it to a stack or remove it or something.

I know how to evaluate keys, versus values...but how do I evaluate values against each other within the same array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a hash to store number of times any element is repeated. Thus iterating over array just once.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
['a','b','b','c'].each{ |e| h[e] += 1 }
```

Should result

```
 {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
```

Comment: Why not `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h[e] += 1`?

Comment: Matter of syntax. It's at  programmers  discretion.

Comment: This is actually what I was trying to do....but...I couldn't figure out how to use the `nil?` and increment methods just like this. Thanks!

Comment: Just improving the current answer

Answer (score 6):

This works efficiently and is rather simple:

```
require 'set'

visited = Set.new
array.each do |element|
  if visited.include?(element)
    # duplicated item
  else
    # first appearance
    visited << element
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class Array
    def find_dups
        uniq.map {|v| (self - [v]).size < (self.size - 1) ? v : nil}.compact
    end
end

a = ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'rat', 'dog', 'cat']

print a - a.find_dups # Removes duplicates
```

`find_dups` will return elements that have duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
array.inject({}){|h, e| h[e] = h[e].to_i + 1; h}
```

Comment: or `array.inject(Hash.new(0)){|h, e| h[e] += 1; h}`

Answer (score 2):

Use 
`a.uniq!` to remove duplicates .

also checkout the [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) where you can find more info on ruby's class methods .

Comment: compact removes nils from the array. How is it helpful in this situation?

Comment: Your solution removes duplicates, it doesn't look for them as OP asked

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to run a double loop:

```
a.each_with_index do |a1, idx1|
  a.each_with_index do |a2, idx2|
    next if idx1 >= idx2 # Don't compare element to itself 
                         # and don't repeat comparisons already made

    # do something with a pair of elements (a1, a2)
  end
end
```

If you just want to eliminate duplicates, there's a method: [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Comment: Thought about this, but it seems so messy. There a more elegant, 'ruby-ish' solution?

Comment: For eliminating duplicates, there's a method. For comparing all elements to each other, there's a double loop. I personally don't see any mess in it. It's plain simple code that reads well.

Comment: Sergio this method is inefficient as you're making unnecessary comparisons that have been made in the past. Your second inner loop should start it's iteration later (i.e. further in the array) on each loop.

Comment: @MMM I didn't say it's efficient. I said it's simple :)

Answer (score 1):

This will print all the duplicates in an array:

```
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,val| 
  hash[val] += 1; 
  hash 
}.each_pair { |val,count| 
  puts "#{val} -> #{count}" if count > 1 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to compare it with a unique version of itself. If its the same then it has no duplicates, if not then duplicates exist.

```
unique_array = original_array.uniq
```

get a unique version of your array

```
if original_array == unique_array then return true else return false
```

compare it to your original array.

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of duplicates, the easiest thing to do is take the array and do array&array. Use the & operator.

If you want to know what those repeats are, just compare array to array&array.

Answer (score 0):

If array is sortable, then something like below will return only the duplicates.

```
array.sort.each_cons(2).select {|p| p[0] == p[1] }.map &:first
```

Sorts the array, then maps it to consecutive pairs of elements, selects pairs which are same, maps to elements.